# Ping problem with Windows Server machine

Tags: networking

We installed 3 computer using windows server 2003 . 
Only one computer is pingable from outside. However I am able to ping any machine on the network from all the 3 computers . I feel that the service that runs PING  is not running on The 2 machines ...although it can ping outside servers ....Can anyone tell me ?

Rgds
Nishant

Comment: I can reframe my question like this , what makes a computer ping machines in the network ---- but will not service a ping request from outside i.e its only acting as a ping client not a PING SERVER

Comment: @Nishant: For future reference, there's no ping "client" and ping "server" and there's no ping service. Ping is a utility built into the networking (TCP\IP) stack in every operating system that has TCP\IP installed. There's nothing special that needs to be done to use ping other than having your firewall(s) configured to allow it.

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely that this error is firewall related. Most firewalls prevent Echo requests (ping) by default. If you are using windows firewall, you need to go into the the firewall settings utility in control panel, go to the advanced tab then click the settings button in the ICMP section. You then need to tick the box that says 'Allow incoming echo requests'

[image]

Comment: Nice answer and thank you for including screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious one is Windows Firewall - disable it in control panel if you don't need it (I'd advise against this TBH) or add an exception (in the 'Exceptions' tab funnily enough)